# How to have an object flip directly on right or left arrow in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform

I am trying to get a GameObject to face right when I press the right arrow and then face left when I press left arrow.

What I currently get is the image to flip back and forth over and over again.  It won't just stay facing left or right.

On occasion it will switch to the left and stay that way even though I am pressing right.  I am sure there is a better way to do this.

```
public bool isFacingRight;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        petAnimate.AnimationName = "run_loop";
    } else
    {
        petAnimate.AnimationName = "start_loop_2";
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
        isFacingRight = true;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
        isFacingRight = false;
    }
    Flip();
}

void Flip()
{
    if (isFacingRight == true)
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0);
    }
    if (isFacingRight == false)
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, 180, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on type of game, 2D or 3D?

Comment: I am doing this in 2D.

Comment: OK, so there are several options but i think one of the simplest is just change scale. E.g create animation of character ruining to the right and just change scale to -1 if characker need to run to the left. There is also posibility to flip animation in `SpriteRenderer` component but i'm not entirly sure if this works with animation, you can check for yourself. I think there is no need to rotate object.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfect :-)  I went with the scaling thing!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply times the X scale by -1. Multiplying by -1 will just turn everything backwards :)

```
void Flip()
{
    // Switch the way the player is labelled as facing
    isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;

    // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;
}
```

Note that this method will work on whichever arrow key you press (left or right). If your character is facing right in your scene, set your `bool` to `true`, otherwise set it to `false`

Answer (score 0):

```
void Flip()
{
    if (isFacingRight == true)
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(.2f, .2f, 0);
    }
    if (isFacingRight ==false)
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-.2f, .2f, 0);
    }
}
```